# Is $L^\infty(\lambda^d) \cong L^\infty(\lambda^{d-1}) \otimes L^\infty(\lambda)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\lambda^d$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^d$. If we take products of functions in $L^\infty(\lambda^{d-1})$ with functions in $L^\infty(\lambda)$, we should get functions in $L^\infty(\lambda^d)$. Can we get all such functions this way? Are all functions in $L^\infty(\lambda^d)$ included in the closed span of linear combinations of elements of $L^\infty(\lambda^{d-1}) \otimes L^\infty(\lambda)$? That is, is
$$L^\infty(\lambda^d) \cong L^\infty(\lambda^{d-1}) \otimes L^\infty(\lambda)$$

Edit: (to include more information about what I have considered)

What I would like to say is that we can approximate indicator functions (and hence simple functions) in $L^\infty(\lambda^d)$ by simple functions in $L^\infty(\lambda^{d-1}) \otimes L^\infty(\lambda)$, but such a statement seems to rely on being able to approximate a measurable set $A \subseteq [0,1]^d$ by measurable rectangles $B_i \times C_i$ (with $B_i \subseteq[0,1]^{d-1}$ and $C_i \subseteq [0,1]$). I'm not sure if such an approximation exists in general. So far, I have only seen results that guarantee pointwise convergence of such functions, not $L^\infty$ convergence. $L^\infty$ convergence seems harder in this case because if $\lambda(A \triangle \bigcup_i (B_i \times C_i)) > 0$, then $d(1_A,\sum_i 1_{B_i \times C_i}) = 1$.

Currently, I think that the answer should be in the negative, but I don't know how to prove that a counterexample exists.

Comment: This is hardly true, but I feel that $L^\infty(\lambda^{d-1})\otimes L^\infty(\lambda)$ is dense in $L^\infty(\lambda^d)$, if the $\otimes$ is the usual algebraic tensor product. If we define $\otimes$ as its completion, then the above equation becomes true, I suppose.

Comment: I had accidentally included an extra $d$ on the lone $\lambda$ on the right (both in the title and body of the question). What I am basically asking is how one would show that $L^\infty(\lambda^{d-1}) \otimes L^\infty(\lambda)$ is dense in $L^\infty(\lambda^d)$.

Comment: Nevermind - what I said is true for $L^2$, but apparently not for $L^\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For $d=2$, on $[0,1]^2$ it is hard to approximate the diagonal functions
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x>y\\
0& \text{ if } x\le y\end{cases}
$$
by products of the type $g(x)h(y)$ in $L^\infty([0,1]^2)$. It is not possible to do this even with infinite series of functions of this type.
Take such a series
$$
F(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k(x) h_k(y)$.
$$
Then the set $\{ F(\cdot,y): y\in[0,1]\}$ is separable, while the same set for the diagonal function $\{ f(\cdot,y):y\in[0,1]\}$ is not separable.

Comment: Can these functions be approximated by linear combinations of products $g(x)h(y)$ in $L^\infty([0,1]^2)$?